# Can't Import Requests into Python: ImportError no module named urllib3

Tags: python, urllib3, hortonworks-sandbox

I've searched on this but other examples I've come across are people having issues installing Requests, my issue is around importing the module:

Using Putty (connected to a HDF 2.4 sandbox session) and Python to call an API.

Last night, I had this working - installed the Requests module no problem, defined Python, and then made the GET request, worked perfect.

Tonight, I've followed the exact same steps, but when I try to 'Import Requests' I'm getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

The steps I've replicated from last night are:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# pip install requests  
python –v
import requests
```

Figure I must have inadvertently changed something... Can anyone please advise?

Comment: have you tried pip install urllib3 ?

Comment: Thanks @NilsZiehn - I've given this a try but would you believe this is now throwing the error: `ImportError: No module named moves.http_client`

Comment: ...so I've tried to `pip install move.http_client` but this now throws the following:  `InsecurePlatformWarning
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement moves.http-client (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for moves.http-client`

Comment: Thanks @AniMenon for the additional tagging

Comment: Just to close on this, I've abandoned trying to figure out a resolution on this issue. I'm instead using Apache Nifi to call the api and dump the data file straight into hdfs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are already on HDF 3.5+ and the sandbox will have changed significantly since this was asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not reproducible anymore as the referenced sandbox should not be available anymore, but in general the recommended approach for sandbox troubles is to start with the fresh sandbox, it is typically faster than troubleshooting.